# Prononciation du mot "linguiste"

Tags: vocabulaire, prononciation, linguistique

Il semblerait que je prononce le mot "linguiste" comme un guignol, puisque hélas je prononce son "gui" comme chez "guignol".

Si je comprends bien, il faudrait faire comme chez "pingouin" ? Ou peut-être comme chez "huître" ? Est-ce que j'ai raison de considérer cette prononciation comme une irrégularité ? Si c'est le cas, y a-t-il d'autres "gui" prononcés comme cela, et quelle est le processus linguistique par lequel on est arrivé là ?

Comment: *Ambiguïté* est écrit avec un tréma (sur le *i*, ou le *u* depuis 1990), mais il y a aussi *aiguille* et *inguinal*, prononcés /gɥi/ comme dans *huître* (ou *huitre*).

Comment: Pour [aiguille](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aiguille) comme pour [linguiste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/linguiste), le TLF donne des références.

Comment: '"Linguiste" is like "ling-W-ist" in English

Comment: @SteffX: Not quite, /w/ as in *oui* /wi/ and /ɥ/ as in *huit* /ɥi(t)/ are distinct phonemes in French.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez  That's the Belgian French pronunciation though.

Comment: In many varieties of France French: joint [ʒwɛ̃] ≠ juin [ʒɥɛ̃].

Comment: Bon moi je n'ai fait -1 nulle part, je sais pas trop ce qui s'est produit. Merci.

Answer (score 2):

La convention d'écriture pour /lingɥistə/, [lɛ̃gɥist], « linguiste », est effectivement étrange mais pas totalement isolée. /egɥijə/, [egɥij], « aiguille » et /ingɥinal/, [ɛ̃gɥinal], « inguinal » déjà cités en commentaires ainsi que /ungɥiz/, [ɔ̃gɥi] « unguis » d'après le TLFi utilisent cette même convention (contrairement à /angijə/, [ɑ̃gij], « anguille »). Pour /gɥijanə/, [gɥijan], la convention est différente, sans doute à cause de la voyelle qui suit : « Guyane ».

Avec les conventions graphiques du français, il y aurait une place pour un contraste entre /gi/ et /gɥi/ avec « gui » vs « guï » :

> ambiguïté, contiguïté, exiguïté

Mais cette option n'a pas été choisie pour ces exceptions (qui se sont étendues récemment au Kinder Pingui).

Il y a une difficulté sous-jacente à la question posée. En général, la lecture consiste à reconnaître un mot existant qui possède déjà sa prononciation propre. Ce problème est bien plus marqué avec les toponymes où la même orthographe conduit à des prononciations différentes suivant les régions.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I rolled back your modifications which did not represent my point of view on the orientation on conventionalization going from spoken French to writing...

Comment: I really don't care about the order, my point was to fix the wrong symbols that you left in the pronunciations.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez The symbols were meant to be phonological representations (between slashes) not phonetic realizations (between brackets). Nasal vowels are generally not considered to be phonemic in French but rather emerge from an underlying sequence of a vowel followed by a nasal consonant not followed by a vowel (VNC or VN#).

Comment: Man, you will have to fix all the dictionaries out there.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez The TLFi respects the convention as does the Robert. And this seems to be your habit too.

Answer (score 0):

*Linguiste* and *inguinal* are scholar's vocabulary so maintain a pronunciation related to the Latin one, unlike *guignol* and other words with *gui*. (This reasoning doesn't work with *aiguille* though.)

In France, the mainstream pronunciation is /lɛ̃gɥist/ although the variant /lɛ̃gwist/ is the norm in Belgium (just like  *huit* is pronounced /wit/) and might be used too in southern France (where *huit* is still /ɥit/).

I suspect even /lɛ̃gist/ might be heard, but probably only from people unfamiliar with the regular pronunciation.

See this very similar question: [Prononciation de équi](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27674/prononciation-de-%C3%A9qui)

Comment: Thanks for the cue to the other question, it is indeed a similar issue.

Comment: Belgians pronouncing [w] what others would pronounce [ɥ] is not specific to this word. Any sources for the possibly larger proportion of [gw] for this specific word in southern France? Where did you get that from?

Comment: I have never heard [lɛ̃gist] and would not have recognized it easily. Both the other pronunciations are used in France in the linguist community (including linguistics labs).

Comment: Le [début](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7x3euzch140nv8d/Linguiste.png?dl=0) de l'[article en question](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43345675?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) pour clarifier le fait que la question ne pose pas vraiment dans ces termes...

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I have no reference outside my personal experience which of course has no scientifc value. My impression is this shift can occur in a wider zone than the Occitan area and includes the Franco-Provencal one. A close and better known non standard pronunciation observed at least in that area is *juin* pronounced \ʒwɛ̃\  vs the expected \ʒɥɛ̃\ . *Aiguille* isn't affected.

Comment: *Juin* is even more peculiar than that, and I don't think it can be related to this topic. Within some area in the south it's [ʒy.ɛ̃] for most of the speakers, whereas [ʒwɛ̃] would be understood as *joint*.

Comment: Yes, [ʒy.ɛ̃] is typical South-West France pronunciation. My experience is more with South-East France. That includes Lyon, Marseilles and Nice. e.g. [*Le grand présentateur Jacques Martin a créé des prononciations qui ont fait école. Désormais, sur les ondes, le mois de Juin se prononce JOUIN*](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=5333) cf. *Juan-les-Pins* local pronunciation too.

Answer (score -3):

Prononce-le : « lin-g-oui-st ».

Comment: Pourquoi? Sources?

Comment: Je travaille dans un laboratoire de linguistique. :) Cela répond à ta question des sources ? En ce qui concerne le pourquoi, cela vient tout simplement du latin lingua qui se prononce linn-gou-a .

Comment: +1 -  Mes sources: c'est ainsi que je le prononce et que je l'entends dans la région toulousaine.

Comment: Je n'en doute pas une seconde, mais une réponse un peu plus étoffée serait la bienvenue.

Comment: Voilà : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/linguiste  Je vois mal comment faire mieux. Tu y trouveras la prononciation exacte ainsi que l'étymologie.

Comment: This is both short and inaccurate as shown by the given link itself. Which definitely licences Toto's question about references...