# Prononciation de équi

Tags: prononciation, latin

Pourquoi le *équi* dans équilatéral et dans équilibre (ou équitable) se prononce différemment ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Équi***latéral se prononce comme ***équi***distant.

Une raison invoquée pour expliquer la prononciation **/ekɥi-/** est que ce sont des mots plus savants qui conservent une proximité avec la prononciation latine alors que d'autres mots comme équilibre ou équitable, qui partagent le même préfixe, se sont alignés sur la prononciation de **qui** en français.

En Belgique, ces mots se prononcent plutôt /**ekwi-**/ alors qu'en Suisse, il semble que la prononciation régulière /**eki-**/ soit la norme.

Answer (score 0):

Cela vient du Latin `aequus` (égal) et selon les cas on le prononce de différentes manières. De façon plus "latine", je dirais, \e.kɥi\ et sinon \e.ki\